# Função de verificação de token não retorna true ou false

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-router

Estou tentando fazer uma função que controla o acesso a algumas rotas `React` da minha aplicação.

Essa função verifica se o usuário está logado ( verifica se ele possui um token), envia uma requisição para a API com o token, verifica se o token enviado é válido ou não, e retorna uma resposta.

• Se a resposta da minha função for `true` (token válido), o usuário poderá acessar a rota.

• Se a resposta da minha função for `false`(token inválido), o usuário é redirecionado para a página de login.

Segue abaixo o código da `api` (instância do axios):

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:4000'
});

export default api;
```

O código da função `tokenVerify()`:

```
import api from "./api"

function tokenVerify(){
    
    const userToken = localStorage.getItem('usertoken')

    if(userToken !== undefined){

         api.post('/tokenverify', userToken
         
         ).then(res => {
            
            const statusRes = res.data.status
            
            if(statusRes === 200){
                return true
            }else{
                return false
            }
            

         }).catch(erro => {
             console.log(erro)
         })      
    }
}

export { tokenVerify }
```

O código da `<PrivateRoute/>` (rota privada do React):

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from 'react-router'
import { tokenVerify } from '../services/tokenVerify'

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (

    <Route { ...rest } render={ props => (

        tokenVerify() ? ( <Component { ...props }/> ) : ( window.location.replace('/') )

    )}/>
)
export default PrivateRoute
```

E o código da rota da API de verificação do token:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

router.post("/tokenverify", (req, res) => {

    const JWTSecret = require('../app')
    
    var reqToken = req.body.usertoken
   
    if(reqToken != undefined){

        jwt.verify(reqToken, JWTSecret, (error, data) => {
           
            if(error){
                res.status(401)
                res.json('Token inválido')

            }else{
                res.status(200);
                res.json('Deu certo')
            }}
)}

})


module.exports = router;
```

A função `tokenVerify()` está sempre retornando `undefined`, e preciso que ela retorne `true` ou `false`. Estou tentando mas ainda não identifiquei o erro. Assisti alguns vídeos e li algumas postagens em fóruns mas ainda não consegui achar algo que me ajude.

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Se o `localStorage.getItem('usertoken')` não existir (ou seja, `null`), vai entrar no `if(userToken !== undefined){`, porque `null` é diferente de `undefined`, porém a função já vai retornar `undefined` porque ela não está retornando nada. Vc está tentando retornar `true` ou `false` dentro de um requisição assíncrona, mas o código não espera por isso.

Comment: Existe alguma maneira de eu pegar a resposta dessa requisição assíncrona e utilizar fora do escopo dela?